# Early access to new SharePoint features - SharePoint Framework and Modern PAges

Tags: sharepoint, office365

What are the options to get early access to the new SharePoint development frameworks and tools - the SharePoint Framework, client web parts and Modern Pages?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Dev PnP Web Cast: http://dev.office.com/blogs/getting-started-with-sharepoint-framework

Answer (score 0):

Well you just need to run a power shell to make your site modern. powershell will enable your to create new Site Pages which are based on the modern site.
 [Powershell script Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/allow-or-prevent-creation-of-modern-site-pages-by-end-users-c41d9cc8-c5c0-46b4-8b87-ea66abc6e63b)

Local workbench , gulp, node you will get in the above shared link. it is very use ful.